# Difference between fetched and returned tuples in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, performance, monitoring

I'm facing a hard time trying to figure it out some performance problems in my database. I'm using a bunch of resources online to learn what to monitor and how to interpret that information.

From the above, I'm unable to find a clear explanation of what is the difference between `pg_stat_database.tup_returned` and `pg_stat_database.tup_fetched`.

In pgAdmin4, there is a beautiful chart called "Tuples out" where these two concepts are contrasted, but I don't know how to interpret the info. In the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW) only says that:

- `tup_returned`: Number of rows returned by queries in this database
- `tup_fetched`: Number of rows fetched by queries in this database

What exactly does "fetched" and "returned" mean?

I'm using postgresql 10.

Comment: In the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/monitoring-stats.html), section Table 28.11. pg_stat_database View

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you do `select count(*) from million_row_table`, one million row wills be returned, but only one row will be fetched.

I can't see I've ever found these fields useful for diagnosing performance problems.  Find your slow query and do an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It's funny that the documentation doesn't explain that clearly. At least I can't find it.

Comment: If there's an **index** for the count, does PG still report millions of rows *returned* or not?